# View does not look correct on iPhone X landscape mode

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, uiview, iphone-x

I have a "**view**" inside a `UITableview` (header) but in landscape mode it does not respect the Safe Area on the `iPhone X`.
[image: Screenshot]

Any suggestions to solve this problem?

**Update:**
Thanks for the suggestions from @matt, @ Tj3n , @AlbertB and @dahiya_boy, I added the "safe area" and with that I solved the problems.

[image: safe Area]

Comment: Usse safegaurd from storyboard left pannel.

Comment: How to add a "safe area"? The UITableViewController does not add

Comment: The problem is your leading and trailing constraints are wrong. In the header view I see two views. The leading edge of the first and the trailing edge of the second need to be pinned with autolayout to the safe area. That way, the header view itself will be wide but the views will be inside the safe area.

Comment: @matt Inside the view there is another view and labels https://i.stack.imgur.com/oTy6A.jpg

Comment: The subviews inside the header view have to respect safe area

Comment: Ok but that doesn’t change what I’m saying. The reason they don’t respect the safe area is you didn’t pin them to the safe area.

Comment: @MarioBurga Use this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46222000/cant-use-safe-areas-in-xcode-9-after-upgrading-minimum-deployment-target-to-ios?rq=1) to unable safe area in storyboard

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the VIEW, make sure you have activated these options.

[image]